# Why does swiftmailer throws an exception error after updating to higher version, In yii2?

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

The following error after updating yii2 (version 2.0.22) to higher version (2.0.32)

 In local host(XAMPP)

> #### Swift_TransportException
>
> Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.
>   ]

Composer.json file after updating: `yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",`

swiftmailer updated to version 2.1.2.0.

Composer.json file before updating: `"yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",` 
yii2-swiftmailer 2.0.7.0: **No problem**

---

**1-** The `default contact page` is used(In Yii2)

**2-** Web.php file

```
config:
      'mailer' => [
      //     'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
          'useFileTransport' => false,
      ],
```

**3-** php.ini

```
SMTP=localhost
smtp_port=25
sendmail_path = "\"H:\Xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

**No problem sending email** with configuring `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` files before updating. (Or restore to "yiisoft / yii2-swiftmailer": "~ 2.0.0", in composer)

[image]

Comment: show your config where you are specifying the mailer settings, and are you on windows by any chance

Comment: also when are you getting this error at the time of sending the mail or  site load a complete error trace might help

Comment: Thankful. I updated the question. Not used by SwiftMiller.